# SYMLINK For usb devices

Tags: usb

I am trying to use 4-6 differnet usb dongles to communicate with hardware from my RPI. I want to give them a static name that I can refer to such as modbus, dmX, arduino1, rpiZero and so on.

Basically on the internet I found two quite differnet examples of symlink files and I do not quite understand the differences and how it should be set up to properly work:

1. `SUBSYSTEM=="tty", ATTRS{idVendor}=="1a86", ATTRS{idProduct}=="7523", OWNER="openhab" SYMLINK="modbus"`
2. `SUBSYSTEM=="usb|usb_device", ACTION=="add", ATTRS{idVendor}=="0403", ATTRS{idProduct}=="6001", GROUP="dialout"`

   1. should every USB dongle have its own rule file or should i put all my usb settings in one file? sudo nano /etc/udev/rules.d/usb.rules
   2. what should the files be called?  whatever.rules ?
   3. what subsystem should it be? tty or usb|usb_device
   4. whats the usb name? /dev/symlinkName or just /symlinkName?
   5. Should I use OWNER or GROUP ?

Answer (score 3):

1. Give them each their own file.
2. `##-name.rules`, e.g., `30-modbus.rules`
3. Run `udevadm info -a -p $(udevadm info -q path -n /dev/<device name>)`. It will most likely be `usb`. Also replace the other fields with the information that appears as appropriate, like `ATTRS{idVendor}` and `ATTRS{idProduct}`.
4. `/dev/symlinkName`
5. That's, as the name says, to set its owner and group, as in any other file; use whatever is appropriate for your needs. If you only need `root` to access it, you can just omit it.

You can find more information at the [Arch Wiki](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Udev#Testing_rules_before_loading).

Comment: Tried follow your suggestions, however : $ udevadm info -a -p $(udevadm info -q path -n /dev/modbus) gives empty return after creating the symlink file. What am I missing?

Comment: @skatun The command is to find out the necessary info for the file; how could you already have it? You're supposed to run it on the `sdX` equivalent since the symlink doesn't exist yet.

Comment: The command is to find out the necessary info for the file; how could you already have it? I created 99-modbus.rules file where I put the info found with lsusb (id and vendor, then I restarted the udev, then I ran the command above. So for some reason the symlink did not get linked. Could it be some root issue? That my user does not have accsess to the symlink? in my program(openhab) it works fine with /dev/ttyusb1 but /dev/modbus does not work.

Comment: @skatun What `SUBSYSTEM` did you use, then? Your user not having access to the symlink shouldn't prevent it from being created; see what happens when you run `udevadm test /dev/sdX`. If it still doesn't work and you're sure you did it correctly, try rebooting.